# Ruby: How do I pass all parameters and blocks received by one method to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a helper that adds an HTML attribute to a link_to tag in rails. So, my thinking is that my helper method should accept any parameters or blocks passed to it, call link_to with those same parameters, add it's attribute to what is returned, and return the result to the caller.

Like this:

```
def link_to(*args, &block)
  ... rails code in link_to ...
end

def myhelper(*args, &block) # Notice that at this point, 'args' has already
  link_to()                 # become an array of arguments and 'block' has
  ... my code ...           # already been turned into a Proc.
end

myhelper() # Any arguments or blocks I pass with this call should make
           # it all the way through to link_to.
```

So, as you can see, there seems to be no way (that doesn't involve lots of code and conditional branching) to pass what myhelper has received to link_to without turning all of the parameters back into what they looked like before they got to my method.

Is there a more 'Ruby-like' solution to this problem?

Comment: Note that in Ruby 2.0, named arguments may also have to be forwarded...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use `*` and `&` in method calls to turn arrays back into lists of arguments and procs back into blocks. So you can just do this:

```
def myhelper(*args, &block)
  link_to(*args, &block)
  # your code
end
```

Comment: I feel stupid now :-) I was sure you were wrong, and I was writing some sample code to prove it, and of course you were right. Thanks!

Comment: @Ajedi32 yes, they are gathered into a hash e.g. `foo(:bar, baz: 'qux')` becomes `[:bar, {:baz=>"qux"}]`.

Answer (score 27):

### def method(...)

Starting from **Ruby 2.7** it is possible to pass all the arguments of the current method to the other method using `(...)`.

So, now,

```
def my_helper(*args, &block)
  link_to(*args, &block)
  
  # your code
end
```

can be rewritten as

```rb
def my_helper(...)
  link_to(...)

  # your code
end
```

Here is [the link to the feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16253).