# How to pass arguments passed in to another method?

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3. I am trying to implement a method in which to run a `send` method and I would like to pass to the "sent" method *all* arguments passed to the underling method. That is, given

```
def method1(arg1, arg2 = true, *args)
  # ...
  self.class.send(:method2, # passing all arguments passed to method1, whatever those are)
end
```

then I would like to pass *all* arguments passed to the `method1` (in this case, `arg1, arg2 = true, *args`) to the `method2`.

How *should* I make that? For example, is it possible to use Ruby "splat" functionalities with `send`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: How do I pass all parameters and blocks recieved by one method to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683844/ruby-how-do-i-pass-all-parameters-and-blocks-recieved-by-one-method-to-another)

Answer (score 4):

Your current method signature `method1(arg1 = true, arg2, *args)` is invalid because the arguments with default values must come after the required arguments if you're also using splat optional arguments. But if you changed this to:

```
method1(arg1, arg2 = true, *args)
```

then you can do

```
self.class.send(:method2, arg1, arg2, *args)
```

Comment: I am looking to pass all arguments to the `method2` whatever arguments are passed to the `method1`. *BTW*: I updated the question so to do not emphasize on the method signature.

Comment: Actually ruby 1.9 does allow default arguments at the start ( see http://www.igvita.com/2011/02/03/new-ruby-19-features-tips-tricks/ for example)

Comment: @Backo You could do something hacky using `Method#parameters` and `eval` but I don't see why you'd need to do this. If you're writing code inside `method1` then you know what parameters it accepts so you can just do as in the answer above. Maybe you need to give a more specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @FrederickCheung cool, but am I right in saying this can't also be combined with optional arguments at the end as the OP has done? so `def method1(a = 1, b)` is fine but not `def method2(a = 1, b, *rest)`?